# What determines if someone going to Heaven or Hell?

Tags: death-parade

What determines if someone going to Heaven (reincarnate) or Hell (void)?

In episode 6, Harada was sent to void despite him repenting his attempt to kill Mayu. Yet, in episode 2, both Chisato and Shigeru was reincarnated, despite Chisato lying to Shigeru about her identity. Yes, Shigeru knows about her identity, but still she is lying to him.

So, what exactly determines the sentence?

Comment: Arbiters determine. But *how* they determine is not super clear.

Comment: the judging is biased

Comment: @Ezui that means anyone who ended in Viginti is screwed then.

Comment: I mean it's solely based on how the arbiter have evaluated the person like when Decim sent Machiko instead of Takeshi from Episode 1 to the void for having the reason that Machiko lied to Takeshi about the baby where in fact it was later seen that Machiko sacrificed herself to save Takeshi. Decim passed on judgment based on his understanding without actually overlooking and analyzing carefully the actions of both. In this case, I think Machiko was supposedly the one to go to Heaven if only Decim was able to realize the true intentions of Machiko before they were sent to their destinations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've been wondering the same myself for some time, and have come to the conclusion that there isn't really a rule as to how to judge the various guests. Every arbiter judges as he or she pleases.

Ginti, for instance, cast Harada into the void because he was about to betray Mayu, pushing her to her death. Ginti didn't care that Harada had a change of heart and *tried* to save her; he would've pushed her in cold blood anyways, had she not decided to jump on her own.

Decim, on the other hand, focused more on the actual result, rather than what *might* have happened. If we look back to episode 1: Takashi (the husband) was sent for reincarnation, despite him betraying his wife (he eventually played to win, after all). Takashi even tried to attack his own wife, only to be stopped by Decim.

Later on, Decim's (in)actions drastically change his style of judgement. In episode 4, Decim doesn't even try to stop Misaki (the TV show hostess) as she repeatedly smashes Yousuke's (the NEET) skull into the screen, probably because the game was still in progress then.

Finally, we have Tatsumi (the fallen detective) and Shimada (the boy whose sister was raped) during episodes 8 and 9. Like before, Decim stops Shimada from attacking Tatsumi after the game's end. Only ***this time***, he provides Shimada with an opportunity to *torture* Tatsumi. Had Decim performed his judgement the same way he did in episode 1, Shimada would probably *not* have been cast into the void.

As for episode 3 (not 2), Mai (aka Chisato) didn't exactly *lie* to Shigeru; not intentionally, at least. At first she didn't remember who she was and as the game progressed, she remembered Shigeru, Chisato, and Mai. Only, she *believed* she was Chisato, and it wasn't until after the game had ended, that she remembered who she *really* was. As soon as she remembered, she tried to tell Shigeru the truth, but he interrupted her, saying he already knew.

---

In the end, there is no real determining factor to the judgements. Every arbiter judges as he or she pleases, and their judgement can change dramatically over time, as seen with the stark contrast between episode 1 and episode 9.